# unable to run a container with volume on glusterfs

Tags: docker, kubernetes, glusterfs

i've a kubernetes cluster with a master node and 3 minions, i've already a glusterfs cluster, every node of kubernetes cluster have glusterfs-client installed and working.
i'm trying to run a pod ( a simple mysql ) mounting /var/lib/mysql on glusterfs but i see:

```
Image: mysql:5.6 is ready, container is creating
```

i run: 
    kubectl get event 
i see:

```
Thu, 18 Feb 2016 10:08:01 +0100   Thu, 18 Feb 2016 10:08:01 +0100   1         mysql-9ym10         Pod                                 scheduled          {scheduler }                Successfully assigned mysql-9ym10 to nodeXX
Thu, 18 Feb 2016 10:08:01 +0100   Thu, 18 Feb 2016 10:08:01 +0100   1         mysql               ReplicationController               successfulCreate   {replication-controller }   Created pod: mysql-9ym10
Thu, 18 Feb 2016 10:08:02 +0100   Thu, 18 Feb 2016 10:08:12 +0100   2         mysql-9ym10         Pod                                 failedMount        {kubelet nodeXX}    Unable to mount volumes for pod "mysql-9ym10_default": exit status 1
Thu, 18 Feb 2016 10:08:02 +0100   Thu, 18 Feb 2016 10:08:12 +0100   2         mysql-9ym10         Pod                                 failedSync         {kubelet nodeXX}    Error syncing pod, skipping: exit status 1
```

if i run 
    kubectl describe pod mysql-9ym10 
i see:

```
Name:                           mysql-9ym10
Namespace:                      default
Image(s):                       mysql:5.6
Node:                           nodeXX/nodeXX
Labels:                         app=mysql
Status:                         Pending
Reason:
Message:
IP:
Replication Controllers:        mysql (1/1 replicas created)
Containers:
  mysql:
    Image:              mysql:5.6
    State:              Waiting
      Reason:           Image: mysql:5.6 is ready, container is creating
    Ready:              False
    Restart Count:      0
Conditions:
  Type          Status
  Ready         False 
Events:
  FirstSeen                             LastSeen                        Count   From                            SubobjectPath   Reason          Message
  Thu, 18 Feb 2016 10:08:01 +0100       Thu, 18 Feb 2016 10:08:01 +0100 1       {scheduler }                                    scheduled       Successfully assigned mysql-9ym10 to nodeXX
  Thu, 18 Feb 2016 10:08:02 +0100       Thu, 18 Feb 2016 10:10:22 +0100 15      {kubelet nodeXX}                        failedMount     Unable to mount volumes for pod "mysql-9ym10_default": exit status 1
  Thu, 18 Feb 2016 10:08:02 +0100       Thu, 18 Feb 2016 10:10:22 +0100 15      {kubelet nodeXX}                        failedSync      Error syncing pod, skipping: exit status 1
```

this is the yaml file for container:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ReplicationController
metadata:
  name: mysql
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    app: mysql
  template:
    metadata:
      name: mysql
      labels:
        app: mysql
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: mysql
        image: mysql:5.6
        ports:
        - containerPort: 3306
        env:
          - name: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
            value: password
        volumeMounts:
          - mountPath: /var/lib/mysql
            name: glusterfsvol
      volumes:
      - glusterfs:
          endpoints: glusterfs-cluster
          path: glustervolume
          readOnly: false
        name: glusterfsvol
```

Answer (score 1):

i've got and endpoint that is configured with glusterfs ip addresses.

i know the posted link, i've followed it but the result is on my first post!

Comment: I have got the same problem. I even successfully mounted a glusterfs volume on a kubernetes node by hand `mount -t glusterfs gluster-node-ip:glustervolume /mnt` but still it does not mount in a pod configured like above.

Comment: well, 5 minutes after i posted this I did manage to get it to work. My local kubernetes environment is based on the vagrant deployment (based on Fedora23). The minikube deployment is based on boot2docker, which is based on Tiny Linux, which as to my knowledge does not have a packaged glusterfs-client. So minikube would not work with glusterfs.

Answer (score 1):

On first: To use a GlusterFS you don't need to install glusterfs-client on kubernetes node. Kubernetes have the volume mounting option for glusterfs by default.

To use a glusterfs with kubernetes you need to things.

1. a working glusterfs server. a running volume in the glusterfs server. I assume you have those. If anyone don't then create a glusterfs server and start your volumes with the following commands

   ```
   $ gluster volume create <volume-name> replica 2 transport tcp \
     peer1:/directory \
     peer2:/directory \
     force
   $ gluster volume start <vonlume-name>
   $ sudo gluster volume info
   ```
2. if this is ok, you need an kubernetes endpoint to use with the pod. as far an example a end point is like this.

   ```
   kind: Endpoints
   apiVersion: v1
   metadata:
     name: glusterfs
   subsets:
   - addresses:
     - ip: peer1
     ports:
     - port: 1
   - addresses:
     - ip: peer2
     ports:
     - port: 1
   ```
3. And at third mount the gfs volume to a pod with the end point.

   ```
         containers:
         - name: mysql
           image: mysql:5.6
           ports:
           - containerPort: 3306
           env:
             - name: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
               value: password
           volumeMounts:
             - mountPath: /var/lib/mysql
               name: glusterfsvol
         volumes:
         - glusterfs:
              endpoints: glusterfs-cluster
              path: <volume-name>
            name: glusterfsvol
   ```

**The path must match the volume name with the glusterfs.

this all should work fine.

Comment: i've got all of this configurations, also glusterfs client on minions.

on endpoint, i'll try to modify configuration, but is very similar...i'll update asap.

thanks.

Comment: check the path with the volume name. and chek the vloume status.

Comment: if you call gluster endpoint GLUSTER, on pod the name of endpoint must match!

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure Endpoints https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/release-1.1/examples/glusterfs/README.md , otherwise kubernetes doesn't know how to access your gluster cluster.